# Keycloak docker image add additional application

Tags: docker, keycloak, docker-multi-stage-build

I have to extend the keycloak docker image for some additional applications like curl and jq. But the image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak hasn't any package manager installed and I can't find which base image was used for building.

My approach is to use a multistage build. But it doesn't work because I don't know from which base image was derived.

```
FROM fedora as builder
RUN dnf update -y && dnf install -y curl
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /usr/bin/curl /bin/curl
```

Someone an idea how can I install the application in the keycloak docker image? Or is anywhere the git repository for the actual keycloak image?

Thank you.

Comment: If the Keycloak image doesn't have a package manager, it's probably a minimal image that contains only the absolute minimum needed for the application to run (this is a pretty common setup in production-oriented images).  It seems unusual that the application would need to call `curl` or `jq`, since most languages include HTTP clients and JSON libraries; why do you need to add them to the Keycloak image specifically?

Comment: I want use curl as healthcheck and jq is needed for some configurations after the start of keycloak. It creates a realm and client and so on. It's for heavy automation. It will setup for different environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way is described here: [container config](https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers)

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9 AS ubi-micro-build
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/rootfs
RUN dnf install --installroot /mnt/rootfs jq curl \
    --releasever 9 --setopt install_weak_deps=false --nodocs -y; \
    dnf --installroot /mnt/rootfs clean all
```

Answer (score 4):

If the curl is used for health check you can use the bash tcp requests instead (bash is present on keycloak image).

An example of a health check:

```yaml
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: timeout 10s bash -c ':> /dev/tcp/localhost/8080'
      start_interval: 10s
```

Comment: Maybe a bit more of explanation of the bash tcp requests syntax would have been nice, otherwise it worked for me rather than `curl`